# Opening .txt file does not show content or traceback but something else

Tags: python

I tried running this code in python. I ensured:
The .txt file was in the same file as the code file and the file name was "random.txt" saved in .txt format

```
    file = input ('Enter File:')
    if len(file) < 1 : file = 'random.txt'
    fhan = open(file)
    print (fhan)
```

My command prompt returned me <_io.TextIOWrapper name='random.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> with no traceback. I don't know how to get the file to open and print the content

Comment: `print(fhan.read())` to print the contents. You're printing the open file object.

Answer (score 0):

Open a file, and print the file content:

```py
with open('./demo.txt', 'r') as file:
    txt = file.read()
    print(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fhan` is a file handle, so printing it simply prints the results of calling its `repr` method, which shows what you see. To read the entire file, you can call `fhan.read()`.

It's also good practice to use a `with` statement to manage resources. For example, your code can be written as

```
file = input('Enter File:')
if not file:  # check for empty string 
    file = 'random.txt'

with open(file, 'r') as fhan:  # use the `with` statement
    print(fhan.read())
```

The benefit of this syntax is that you'll never have to worry about forgetting to close the file handle.